# How to set a constraint depending on previous set index

Tags: pyomo

I am writing an energy optimization model using Pyomo. In this model I have a constraint which updates the charge level of an energy storage at every time-step using the charge level in the previous time-step (simplified equation):

`Storage_level[t] = Storage_level[t-1] + Charge [t] - Discharge [t]`

And there is an additional constraint for the initial period:

`Storage_level[1] = 0`

When I run the problem, I don't get any useful result and the output window just displays the constraint bounds, such as:

```
ev_soc_max : Size=24
    Key : Lower : Body : Upper
      1 :  None : None :   0.0
      2 :  None : None :   0.0
      3 :  None : None :   0.0
      4 :  None : None :   0.0
      5 :  None : None :   0.0
      ...
```

and I also get this error for some variables:

```
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: p_bat_ch[1]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object p_bat_ch[1]
```

I suspect that the problem is related to the definition of the storage constraints.

This is how I coded it in Pyomo (I came to this result by combining different examples which I found here and there on the internet):

```py
def bat_soc_ini_rule(model, t):
    if t == 1:
        return model.e_bat_t[t] == 0.
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip
model.bat_soc_ini = Constraint(model.T, rule = bat_soc_ini_rule)

def bat_soc_rule(model, t):
    if t >= 2:
        return model.e_bat_t[t] == model.eta_bat_cal * model.e_bat_t[t-1] + model.eta_bat_ch * model.p_bat_ch[t] - model.eta_bat_dis**-1 * model.p_bat_dis[t]
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip
model.bat_soc = Constraint(model.T, rule = bat_soc_rule)
```

I should also state that I declared the `model.T` set using `model.T = RangeSet(24)` and the variables are declared as follows: `model.e_bat_t = Var(model.T, within = NonNegativeReals)`

One last point: I am using GLPK as a solver.

My questions are:

1. How should I declare a constraint which calls a previous member of the set? Am I doing it right?
2. How should I set a constraint on only part of a set (e.g. for the initialization constraint)?
3. Am I right in thinking that the error comes from the incorrect definition of this constraint? If not, do you have any idea where the problem could come from?

Comment: I don't see any problem with how you've declared your constraints. In order to debug your model I would recommend using the `model.pprint()` function to print out the model and manually verify that the constraint expressions are what you expect. You should also add the `tee=True` option to your call to `solve` to display the solver output and check for any issues there.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was wondering what was going on with the solver, and didn't know how to retrieve the information from the solver. It didn't solve the problem, but gives me some more tools to help me find a solution.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that this has helped me to identify that the solver does run, but gives as output: PROBLEM HAS NO PRIMAL FEASIBLE SOLUTION.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am working with [urbs](https://github.com/tum-ens/urbs) atm and following code comes from it.

This is the constraint rule you are looking for `storage[t] = storage[t-1] + in - out`

```
# storage content in timestep [t] == storage content[t-1] * (1-discharge)
# + newly stored energy * input efficiency
# - retrieved energy / output efficiency
def def_storage_state_rule(m, t, sit, sto, com):
    return (m.e_sto_con[t, sit, sto, com] ==
            m.e_sto_con[t-1, sit, sto, com] *
            (1 - m.storage_dict['discharge'][(sit, sto, com)]) ** m.dt.value +
            m.e_sto_in[t, sit, sto, com] *
            m.storage_dict['eff-in'][(sit, sto, com)] -
            m.e_sto_out[t, sit, sto, com] /
            m.storage_dict['eff-out'][(sit, sto, com)])
```

And for setting the init value they have something like following:

```
# initialization of storage content in first timestep t[1]
# forced minimun  storage content in final timestep t[len(m.t)]
# content[t=1] == storage capacity * fraction <= content[t=final]
def res_initial_and_final_storage_state_rule(m, t, sit, sto, com):
    if t == m.t[1]:  # first timestep (Pyomo uses 1-based indexing)
        return (m.e_sto_con[t, sit, sto, com] ==
                m.cap_sto_c[sit, sto, com] *
                m.storage_dict['init'][(sit, sto, com)])
    elif t == m.t[len(m.t)]:  # last timestep
        return (m.e_sto_con[t, sit, sto, com] >=
                m.cap_sto_c[sit, sto, com] *
                m.storage_dict['init'][(sit, sto, com)])
    else:
        return pyomo.Constraint.Skip
```

I hope this example helps you. You can use it change it or adapt it in your code-

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. Actually, I have given up on using Pyomo, and started using PuLP instead, which I find more convenient and easier to use for MILP problems. After switching to PuLP, it turned out that the way my constraints were set for the storage made the problem infeasible. Now my model runs OK in PuLP, but I haven't taken the time yet to go back to fix the model in Pyomo as well to see if it solves it. If I get round to it I'll let you know.

Comment: Are you sure that `t-1` in `m.e_sto_con[t-1, sit, sto, com]` works? I still get an error saying it can only concatenate `str`.